# Creating TAB-separated values from .xlsx with ssconvert

Tags: tabs, export-to-csv, import-from-excel, gnumeric, ssconvert

Due to commas within cell values, I am not able to use the `ssconvert` utility for `.xls(x)` to .csv conversion.

Is there a possibility to create tab-separated values directly from `xlsx` with `ssconvert` (command line spreadsheet format converter)?

`ssconvert infile.xlsx outfile.tsv` raises the error:

> Unable to guess exporter to use

Hence, I have tried to generate a raw text file under specification of some export options, in particular, the separator:

`ssconvert -O 'separator=\t format=raw' infile.xlsx outfile.txt`

which results in output like `value1\tvalue2\tvalue3`, i.e., string `\t` is not translated into tabulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When called from a shell-script: Put a real tab-character between allowed quotes, e.g:

```
ssconvert -O 'separator="   " format=raw' infile.xlsx outfile1.txt
ssconvert -O "separator=\"  \" format=raw" infile.xlsx outfile2.txt
ssconvert -O "separator='   ' format=raw" infile.xlsx outfile3.txt
```

To type this directly into a command shell a  ctrl-v before the tab might be necessary.
Pasting this with the mouse will probably fail, as the tab will be replaced by spaces.

Comment: Works perfectly as shell script, but I was not able to make it run directly from command line.

Comment: Can you type the following line ...
    echo "<TAB>"  |  od -c

... and get the following output ?

    0000000  \t  \n
    0000002

I can type this under normal bourne shell ("/bin/sh") without any escape characters, but I need a <CTRL>-V before the <TAB> when I use /bin/bash.

How to enter the <TAB> depends not only on the shell.
Other Layers (XClient, Terminal...) can also "eat the tab away" for something else (like expansions, command completion ...)